# pattern matching find the greater than symbol using regular expression

Tags: regex, string, pattern-matching

I need a regular expression so that if I search for ">" greater than.

**for example**

for this string I will get true - "if x> 2"

and for this string I will get false "`<template>`"

I have tried this -  `[^<][a-zA-Z0-9_]+[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*>`
as the regular expression 
but the problem is that it finds a substring that match 
for example in `<template>`  it finds  `template>`  and return true.

thanks.

**EDIT:**

I am using this regular expression `[^<a-zA-Z0-9_][a-zA-Z0-9_]+[ ]*>` tried it over the entire firefox 1.0 source code and it seem to be working fine.

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*` quickly after `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` doesn't gives sense.

Comment: how will you deal with the string "x<2 and y>3" ?

Comment: What regex dialect/programming language are you using?

Comment: Please format your code appropriately. Thanks!

Comment: i am using python ,about the [a-zA-Z0-9_ ]* quickly after [a-zA-Z0-9_]+ its for the space - i guess i can just put [ ]* insted of the first one, no ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want to match lines that contain `>` but not `<`. This pattern will do that:

```
/^(?=.*>)[^<]+$/
```

However, I'm curious why you want to do this. It sounds suspiciously like you're trying to parse HTML with regular expressions, which **[is usually A Bad Idea.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)**

**EDIT:**

It's clearer now what you're trying to do, but you should be aware that this pushes the limits of what regular expressions are capable of. They can't really tell the difference between a template declaration and text with angle brackets in it, but if you know your template declarations all match a very specific pattern, you can do a pretty good job of catching them.

If all your template declarations follow the `<[0-9]+template>` pattern, you can do this:

```
/^.*(?<!<\d+template)>.*$/
```

If your templates don't follow such a strict convention, you need a true C++ parser for this. It will be basically impossible for regex to tell the difference between a template declaration and this:

```
a=b<c>d;
```

...which is valid code in C++ (translating, I believe, to `a = (b < c) > d;`).

Comment: i am trying to find greater than occurrences in a c source code but i dont want to find <templates>

Comment: @yossi - Okay. This regex should do that unless the template declaration spans multiple lines. This should be a simple enough task for regex to fit your needs 99.9% of the time, but if you need a *really* robust solution, you're going to need a context-aware parser (i.e. something that can actually understand C code).

Comment: that didnt work, its not that i want "to match lines that contain > but not <. " because i should find things like this "x<2 and y>3"

Comment: @yossi - Do all your templates follow the `<_template>` naming convention? Do they all have the word "template" in the declaration? I haven't done C++ for a while; can there be nested brackets (e.g. `<1template<2template>>`)?

Comment: no they dont all have the word "tmeplate" in them. about the nesting of brackets i dont know.

Comment: @yossi - In that case, you can save some time with regex, but what you really need is a C++ parser or an IDE with a "Find All References"-type feature. See edit.

Answer (score 3):

A regex seems like the wrong tool for the job you're trying to do.  You'll probably require a full-blown C++ parser to reliably distinguish ">" the greater-than operator
from ">" the template delimiter, or ">" as part of a string literal or comment.

Comment: i want to avoid that :), i dont need it to fit 100% of the time